# Print layout vector lines too thin

Tags: qgis

When I move my map to Print Layout, all the lines of my vector layers are incredibly thin. How can I make them thicker in Print Layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should work with map units for the line width. If you are already using map units, set the sizes so that they work for your desired scale (*it can be useful to set the same scale in your main map view using the option on your status bar and lock it*).

[image]

You could also set a fixed reference scale for the datasets, using the option found in the `Layer Properties`, under the `Render` tab.

[image]

Comment: Yes! Checking the fixed reference scale for each layer worked. Thank you!

Comment: Follow up question, I'm working in Print Layout and my transect lines are fine, but my scale bar is so thin. I've tried going through all the item properties and I can make the font bigger, but can't get the scale bar thicker. Is this a similar problem?

Comment: I would suggest you mark the above answer as 'accepted'. Now, if the units are fine, it should be a size issue. Check the `Segments` [properties](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/composer_items/composer_scale_bar.html?highlight=segments#segments) where there is a `Height` option. Does it solve your problem?